# Designing capacitor or resistor systems where capacitor or resistor can bear limited voltage

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, mathematics, optimization

> A capacitance of $2\ \mu F$ is required in an electrical circuit
>   across a potential difference of $1.0\ kV$. A large number of $1\ \mu F$
>   capacitors are available which can withstand a potential difference
>   of not more than $300\ V$. The minimum number of capacitors required
>   to achieve this is

(JEE Mains 2017 Paper A Question 15)

Answer given is 32. We place $8$ capacitors in parallel to create an arrangement of capacitance $8\ \mu F$. Then place $4$ such arrangements in series.

Is there a way to **prove** this is the best solution?

Comment: I've edited the rest of the question out because I did actually find a counterexample for the general case. So I guess it's now only a matter of why it works in this specific case. Is it just something to do with which numbers are divisible by which numbers?

Comment: You need 4 capacitors in series so that the total voltage across them does not exceed $1\,\rm  kV$ - they will have a maximum of $250 \,\rm  V$ across each of them.  
This gives you a capacitor with capacitance of $\frac 14 \, \rm \mu F$  
Then you need eight such series arrangements in parallel to produce a capacitor of capacitance $2 \, \rm \mu F$

Comment: A mathematical proof that it's optimal sounds like a tricky optimization problem for an unknown number of elements.

Comment: @Stephen Yeah I later got the feeling that's the case. If such a proof is not useful to anyone, I could delete the question.